# Program in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

Task:Write to the new file all the lines of the source file that contain the specified string as a fragment, which is entered from the keyboard.

I can't figure out how to compare the lines from the file line by line in the Prolog with the fragment that I entered from the keyboard and output the matching lines to a new file.I will be glad to receive any advice or direction. I can't think straight in the prologue.

```
f:-    
   write('Enter the name of the source file:'),  
   read(SOURFILE), 
   check_exist(SOURFILE), 
   open(SOURFILE,read,FROM),
   read_line_to_string(FROM,X),writef(" "),
   writef(X),
   writeln(" "),
   write('Enter a substring:'),
   read(WR),
   close(FROM),
   write('Enter the name of the new file:'),
   read(NEWFILE),
   check_exist(NEWFILE),
   name(S,X),
   write_to_file(NEWFILE,S).
        
check_exist(Filename):-exists_file(Filename),!.
   check_exist(_):-writeln('There is no such file'),
   fail.

write_to_file(Filename,TEXT) :-
   open(Filename, write, File),
   write(File, TEXT),nl,
   writeln('Data recorded successfully'),
   close(File).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use predicate [`sub_string/5`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_string/5) to verify whether a string contains a substring. Thus, to solve your problem, you can do something like this:

```
copy(From, To, Substring) :-
   open(From, read, Input),
   open(To, write, Output),
   repeat,
   read_line_to_string(Input, String),
   (   String = end_of_file
   ->  !        % stop reading lines
   ;   sub_string(String, _, _, _, Substring),
       writeln(Output, String),
       fail ),  % backtracks to read next line
   close(Input),
   close(Output).
```